holomorphic bound $\frac{\left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right| + \left| z\right| }{1 + \left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right| \left| z\right| }$

Let $f \in  H\left( {B\left( {0, 1}\right) }\right), f\left( {B\left( {0, 1}\right) }\right)  \subset  B\left( {0, 1}\right)$.Prove that $$\frac{\left| \right| f\left( 0\right) \left| -\right| z\left| \right| }{1 - \left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right| \left| z\right| } \leq  \left| {f\left( z\right) }\right|  \leq  \frac{\left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right|  + \left| z\right| }{1 + \left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right| \left| z\right| }.$$

My attempt: If we use Schwarz-Pick, $f(0)=b$, then we see
$|\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{1-\overline{f(0)}f(z)}|\leq |z|$
Hence, $|f(z)|\leq |f(0)|+|z|[1+|f(0)|\cdot |f(z)|]$, we get $\left| {f\left( z\right) }\right|  \leq  \frac{\left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right|  + \left| z\right| }{1 - \left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right| \left| z\right| }$, but not $\left| {f\left( z\right) }\right|  \leq  \frac{\left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right|  + \left| z\right| }{1 + \left| {f\left( 0\right) }\right| \left| z\right| }$. How to fix it?

Search MSE. This has been asked before.

@geetha290krm I could not locate it. Some hints?

@MartinR The problem is not the same, so I suspect the validity of my problem, I could not find a counterexample now.

This https://math.stackexchange.com/q/629913/42969 looks identical, doesn't it? But I did not verify the solution

I am not sure if the answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/629913/42969 are correct, but something is wrong here as well: If $f(0) = 0$ then your inequality chain becomes $|z| \le |f(z)| \le |z|$, which is wrong e.g. for $f(z) = z/2$. Note that there are no absolute values signs around the numerator on the left-hand side in the referenced question. – Do you have a source for this problem?
